# How to connect a machine on VPN to AWS PHZ DNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-vpc

I have an AWS VPC with Private Hosted Zone (PHZ) setup so all machines launched within the VPC can resolve my console-defined domains, for example `a1.mydomain`.

I would like for on-site machines at the end of my VPN (not in VPC but connected to a VPN server machine in the VPC) to be able to resolve these PHZ domains as well.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to resolve PHZ, the request must come from the DNS resolver of the VPC:

- Setup a DNS server on the VPN instance that forwards queries of `a1.mydomain` to the [VPC DNS resolver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html) which is the third address of your VPC network (.2)
- Make sure to setup the DNS server to forward other queries to a public DNS server like Google (8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4) or CloudFlare (1.1.1.1)
- Setup the VPN to push its own private IP as a DNS server to users
- On-premise machines connected to the VPN will be able to resolve records in PHZ

Using a bind9 + OpenVPN works quite well

Comment: What is nameserver `127.0.0.53`? This is the only nameserver in the out-of-box DNS `/etc/resolv.conf` file which is apparently sufficient for domains to be resolved by the VPC DNS...

Comment: Anyway I managed to do what you said and get it to work using `dnsmasq` instead of `Bind`. Cheers.